# Which type of API gateway does Chalice generates? Regional or Edge-optimized?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, chalice

I've using [AWS Chalice](https://github.com/aws/chalice) for my projects many times. Recently, one of my clients want to have a custom domain for the API gateway. I checked up [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html) and found out that AWS API gateway endpoints can be either **edge-optimized** or **regional**. And we need to follow through different steps for these two types of endpoints.

I went through the AWS Chalice [documentation](https://chalice.readthedocs.io/), but I cannot find which type of API endpoints Chalice generates. Is it edge-optimized or regional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've used Chalice many times, you can just check in the AWS Console for the API Gateway endpoint and see the type for yourself. They are created as edge optimized. There is an open issue in GitHub to add support for [regional endpoints](https://github.com/aws/chalice/issues/956).